# Single domain to multiple redirects (Redirecting)

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, redirect, dns, subdomain

Will ask you question by an example :-

So here we go :)

I am getting 100 visits a day on www.mywebsite.com

I am redirecting the user to anothter website.

So my question is can I redirect random 50 to another website1.com and rest 50 to another website2.com

IS IT POSSIBLE ?

Comment: is it related to some link rotator script ??

Comment: How are you redirecting them now?

Comment: Right now I'm just able to redirect it to only one but I want to redirect it two or more than two links.

Comment: I understand, but are you using `.htaccess` ProxyPass or RewriteRule or something else?

Comment: I really am new to it and don't know maybe I should call goDaddy assistance for that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Application_BeginRequest` on `global.asax` with a check that is an `.aspx` page to make the redirect as you ask

```
static int cCounter = 0;   

protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sExtentionOfThisFile = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(HttpContext.Current.Request.Path);
    if (sExtentionOfThisFile.Equals(".aspx", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;

        if (++cCounter % 2 == 0)
        {
            app.Response.Redirect("http://site1.com", true);
        }
        else
        {
            app.Response.Redirect("http://site2.com", true);
        }           
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's only for aspx page but I want to use it on domain hosting and I;m having my domain hosting on godaddy.com cam you help me with according to it?

Comment: @bhamrahcoolpreet This is it. And the default page is ending on .aspx (try it)